# Backbone Router + RewriteRule not triggering route with a "/"

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, backbone.js, router

I convert all links from `example.com/action` to `example.com/index.html#action` which is then parsed by my Backbone router.

However, my new page, `signup/:inviteAuthHash` (eg. `signup/9d519a2005b3dac8802d8e9e416239a1`) is not working; the only thing that renders is my `index.html`, and none of my breakpoints in my router are met.

.htaccess:

```
# not a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# example.com/home => example.com/index.html#home
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html#$1 [L,QSA]
```

router.js

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend( {
    routes : {
        /* PAGES */
        // beta
        'request_invite' : 'request_invite',
        'signup/:inviteAuthHash' : 'signup',

        // Default
        '*actions' : 'defaultAction'
    },

    /* PAGES */
    // eta
    request_invite : function() {
        new BetaLayout;
        new RequestInviteView;
    },
    signup : function(inviteAuthHash) {
        // validate auth hash
        if(!InviteRequest.isValidInviteAuthHash(inviteAuthHash))
            return this.defaultAction();
        else {
            new BetaLayout;
            new SignupView(SignupView);
        }
    },

    // Default
    defaultAction : function(actions) {
        app_router.navigate('request_invite');
        this.request_invite();
    }
});

var initialize = function() {
    app_router = new AppRouter;

    $('a').live('click', function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        // only navigate to real links
        if(href == undefined)
            return;

        // open in new window?
        if($(this).prop('target') == '_blank')
            return true;

        app_router.navigate(href, {trigger: true});

        return false;
    });

    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
};
return {
    initialize : initialize
};
```

Comment: My mod_rewrite is a bit rusty but does `RewriteRule` actually send a 301 or 303 back to the browser or is it an internal redirect?

Comment: @Garrett i think `signup/9d519a2005b3dac8802d8e9e416239a1` will translate down to url `index.html/#signupindex.html/#9d519a2005b3dac8802d8e9e416239a1` because of two `/`, `/`. i might be wrong too. another doubt does your invitation hash contain character `:`? then this won't work

Comment: @muistooshort - It depends whether you use the [R] flag or not. If not then it transparently tunnels through (client receives a 200).

Comment: # denotes a comment in .htaccess. Is this causing the problem?

Comment: @AdityaManohar: I don't see an `[R]` so that means that it is an internal redirect, the client will never see `index.html#...`, and no hash means no client-side routing will take place. Assuming that `#` isn't treated as a comment in that context as @Scott suggests.

Comment: Nothing seems to be working, but I have some research findings. I modified the rul to `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ #$1 [L,QSA]`, in which case `http://pumpup.local#signup/9d519a2005b3dac8802d8e9e416239a1` reroutes properly. However, replacing the `#` with a `/` in the url causes it to fail, once again. I cannot find anything useful in my access/error logs.

Comment: Also, adding `[R]` caused an exceeding of 10 internal redirects. I don't think `[R]` is part of the solution here, because part of `pushState` is that it is silent to the client.

Comment: Changing the rule to `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html [L,QSA]` has the same effect as the previously mentioned rule - it seems as though the `#` is, in fact, commenting out the rest of the rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this .htaccess instead:

```
# not a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# example.com/home => example.com/index.html#home
RewriteRule (?!^index\.html)^(.+)$ /index.html#$1 [L,NC,R,NE]
```

Comment: That redirects me to a local file under my `C:/` directory. What does `(?!^index\.html)` do?

Comment: `(?!^index\.html)` is a negative lookahead RegEx that makes sure to forward to `index\.html` ONLY IF URI doesn't have `index.html` at the start. Can you try: `RewriteRule (?!^index\.html)^(.+)$ /index.html#$1 [L,NC,R]`

Comment: Ah, I see. For a page like my dashboard, `/dashboard`, it redirects to `/index.html%23dashboard` (an invalid url). I tried escaping the `#` but had no luck. When I removed the `R` it started working again for normal urls, but didn't fix the original problem (for urls with more than 1 `/`).

Comment: Hmm I think you need an additional `NE` flag. Please check my edited answer now. This rule will now redirect `/foo/bar/baz` to `/index.html#foo/bar/baz`. Also I believe `/dashboard` is not a physical directory under DOCUMENT_ROOT (since we're avoiding them using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` condition)

Comment: Thanks! `NE` was the exact flag that was missing! The `index.html` part was causing problems for Backbone, though, but changing it to `RewriteRule (?!^index\.html)^(.+)$ /#$1 [L,NC,R,NE]` works. Unfortunately, this does reload the page for every link followed (which is not making use of `pushState`, but I can live without that for now. What matters is that it works.

Comment: You're most welcome, glad that it worked for you and you accepted and awarded bounty to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another, in my opinion better solution to your problem: the use of pushState.

So what you do is

1. change your server configuration so that all urls under example.com except your assets actually render index.html (my apache knowledge is rusty, but that should not be hard to do).
2. change your call to Backbone.history.start to enable pushstate, and specify the root, `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/"})`, see [Backbone documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#History-start)

On browsers that support pushstate, the url will display as it should and everything works, on older browsers backbone will automatically convert it to a url with a hash.

Comment: I'm already doing (1) and (2). I didn't have `root: "/"` so I added that, but `/signup/6efa34df09a031a018dc7627dc8509f7` still doesn't work - I have to change it to `#signup/6efa34df09a031a018dc7627dc8509f7`.